# While creating dynamic two dimensional array, what is the use of c in A[i * c+ j], i.e., what does c represent?

Tags: c++

```
int *val r,c;
cout << "enter dimensions";
cin >> r >> c;
val = new int[r*c];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    cout << “\n Enter element in row “ << i + 1 << “ : “;
    for (int j=0; j < c; j++)
        cin >> arr [ i * c + j];
}
```

In the above code, what does `c` represents in expression `arr[i*c+j]`? but in normal two dimensional array we use `arr[i][j]` and what is the meaning of `val = new int[r*c]`? while creating a dynamic array I think `[r*c]` is the total size of array rows into column assigning to the variable var or something else? If I am not using `c` it gives an error but when I am using `c` it will not give an error. Please tell me why we are using `c` in `arr[i*c+j]`. Somewhere I read `c` means the maximum number of columns.

```
int *p = new int;
if(!p)
{
    cout << "memory allocation";
}
```

Also, in the above snippet, how memory allocation is possible if the condition is `true`?

Comment: the first line of this code is strange. Wouldn't it be `int *val, r, c;` ?

Comment: Are you asking what `i * c + j` calculates? What you've got is a 2D array stored as a 1D array. Usually you calculate the index via `coord_y * max_x + coord_x`. In this case `c` is the total number of columns (aka max_x).

Comment: Your second question: If memory allocation fails, `std::bad_alloc` is thrown (at least if you don't turn off exceptions). So in standard C++ environment, you don't have to check the result of allocation via `operator new`. (But you do have to if you use malloc for whatever reason! You shouldn't anyway, only *very* few exceptions force you to still use it, mainly if you pass the pointer to some C-API claiming ownership of - something very rare, haven't met any in 15 years...).

Comment: You **don't** have a "two dimensional array". You are using a single array (so the allocation is contiguous) indexed by a calculation from two dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Tip:

These two codes are doing the same thing.

Code 1:

```
const int N = 3;

int arr[N][N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = SOMETHING;
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
const int N = 3;

int arr[N*N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        arr[i * N + j] = SOMETHING;
    }
}
```

In the first code, the classic syntax for a bidimensional array is used. In the second code, a one-dimension array is used to represent a bidimensional array.